# Deserializing nested JSON in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization

I have tried and exhausted many of the solutions I could find for simply being able to deserialize the follow response I am getting from my node server.

```
[{"treeData":"[{\"title\":\"GroupTitle\",\"nodeItemIds\":[5,1,3],\"children\":[]}] }]
```

I have set up my classes as the following:

```
[Serializable]
public class Groups
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string tagClass { get; set; }
    public List<string> tagIds { get; set; }
    public List<Groups> children { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ResponseData
{
    public string treeData { get; set; }
}
```

And I am attempting to use

```
ResponseData responseData = JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseData>(www.downloadHandler.text);
string jsonString = Regex.Unescape(responseData.treeData);
List<Groups> groups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Groups>>(jsonString);
```

But this gives me the following error `ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type.`

I don't know where I am going wrong. Any help on how I can deserialize this data into my classes is HUGELY appreciated.

Comment: Last I looked, Unity couldn't deserialize lists, try changing them to arrays.

Comment: the json posted in the question, it's for ``jsonString`` or ``responseData`` variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your Json is broken.

`[{"treeData":"[{\"title\":\"GroupTitle\",\"nodeItemIds\":[5,1,3],\"children\":[]}] }]`

Even disregarding escaping properly, you are missing a doublequote. This is how it should look.

`[{"treeData":"[{\"title\":\"GroupTitle\",\"nodeItemIds\":[5,1,3],\"children\":[]}]"}]`

Other than that, your code looks like it ought to work.